# ¿Como mostrar el json de menor a mayor?

Tags: javascript

tengo una pregunta estoy trabajando con una api rest.. y quería mostrar el json en un tabla eso lo hago pero me piden que lo haga en orden alfabético, el json guarda información de los alumnos con nombre y apellido. ¿Cómo puedo mostrarlos en orden alfabético?

```
"notas": [
    {
      "_id": "5d2929ab34254e000450d130",
      "group": "68",
      "thingtype": "notas",
      "thing": {
        "nombre": "",
        "apellido": "Caballero",
        "Dni": "",
        "notauno": "",
        "notados": "",
        "notatres": ""
      },
      "dateAdded": "2019-07-13T00:45:31.399Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5d2929af34254e000450d131",
      "group": "68",
      "thingtype": "notas",
      "thing": {
        "nombre": "",
        "apellido": "Lopez",
        "Dni": "",
        "notauno": "",
        "notados": "",
        "notatres": ""
      },
      "dateAdded": "2019-07-13T00:45:35.474Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "5d292a6b34254e000450d132",
      "group": "68",
      "thingtype": "notas",
      "thing": {
        "nombre": "",
        "apellido": "Arras",
        "Dni": "",
        "notauno": "",
        "notados": "",
        "notatres": ""
      },
      "dateAdded": "2019-07-13T00:48:43.959Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
```

Comment: nos muestras que has intentado?

Comment: con el método `sort` lo logras, lee este enlace [método sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort) y ve a la zona de ordenamiento de objetos y con eso tienes tu solución

Answer (score 1):

Puedes lograr el resultado deseado haciendo uso de la función `Array.prototype.sort`, la cual recibe una función callback `compareFunction(a,b)` de manera opcional y que te sera útil para determinar el criterio de ordenamiento aplicado, teniendo en cuenta los siguientes aspectos expuestos en la documentación de la [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort):

- Si compareFunction(a, b) es menor que 0, se sitúa a en un indice menor que b. Es decir, a viene primero.
- Si compareFunction(a, b) retorna 0, se deja a y b sin cambios entre ellos, pero ordenados con respecto a todos los elementos diferentes.
- Si compareFunction(a, b) es mayor que 0, se sitúa b en un indice menor que a.
  compareFunction(a, b) siempre debe retornar el mismo valor dado un par especifico de elementos a y b como sus argumentos. Si se retornan resultados inconsistentes entonces el orden de ordenamiento es indefinido.

### TL;DR

Te dejo un ejemplo de código usando la estructura que muestras en tu código en donde ordeno por apellido:

```
const jsonStruct = [
    {
        "_id": "5d2929ab34254e000450d130",
        "group": "68",
        "thingtype": "notas",
        "thing": {
            "nombre": "",
            "apellido": "Caballero",
            "Dni": "",
            "notauno": "",
            "notados": "",
            "notatres": ""
        },
        "dateAdded": "2019-07-13T00:45:31.399Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d2929af34254e000450d131",
        "group": "68",
        "thingtype": "notas",
        "thing": {
            "nombre": "",
            "apellido": "Lopez",
            "Dni": "",
            "notauno": "",
            "notados": "",
            "notatres": ""
        },
        "dateAdded": "2019-07-13T00:45:35.474Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5d292a6b34254e000450d132",
        "group": "68",
        "thingtype": "notas",
        "thing": {
            "nombre": "",
            "apellido": "Arras",
            "Dni": "",
            "notauno": "",
            "notados": "",
            "notatres": ""
        },
        "dateAdded": "2019-07-13T00:48:43.959Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]

const orderedStruct = jsonStruct.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.thing.apellido > b.thing.apellido) return 1
    if (a.thing.apellido < b.thing.apellido) return -1
    return 0
})
```

### Referencias

Array.prototype.sort. MDN Web docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort